why is my flutter app opening a deep link url in the browser and not automatically opening route in app?
I have tried in both the iOS simulator and Android Studio simulator to run my deep linking test. Android worked in the event that android:launchMode="singleTop" because it rendered the app screen wrapped inside messenger (where i pasted the url). However, after changing singleTop to singleTask to prevent app wrap, the simulator started acting like the iOS simulator and opening the link in the browser.
this tells me theres something wrong with my configuration or domain. Because no matter what url i try, https://bbtechnologies.org/join/:profileId or https://bbtechnologies.org/details, the device opens the url in the browser and returns the obvious 404 because the link is invalid in the browser.
I have correctly setup my .xml file for android, specified android:launchMode="singleTask", android:value="true", and the scheme:"https", host:"bbtechnologies.org", and pathPrefix="/join/". I have also correctly setup my assetlinks.json file to include the bundleId org.bbtechnologies.shutterspace, and verifying the same sha256 as my firebase android setup. My .json file is store in my domain root directory .well-known/ - managed by Cpanel.
For ios, i have correctly setup my Associated Domains to include applinks:bbtechnologies.org, and because i am using an https deep link, i followed the Universal Link setup. I created my apple-app-site-associated file with the same teamId as my apple developer account teamid for the teamId.bundleid. for now i have specified my paths: [""] and components "/": "/". This json file is also stored in the same directory as my assetlinks.json file at the domain root directory.
Lastly, i setup my GoRouter to handle the route '/join/:profileId'. I've checked my routing configuration and with manual nav within the app; everything works. So the route has no issues.
After verifying my setup for both android and ios, regardless of which simulator i use (iOS or Pixel), simulating the url or clicking the url from another app, the device opens the url in the device browser and obviously returns a 404. I have tried both app_links package and with only GoROuter, following the basic steps from this article. Even with my physical device and 'copying url from notes app', my device will open the url in browser rather than the app.
I have also verified that both my domain does not have any redirects and the app configuration within device settings allows url launch. What's going on and why is my device not using the app to open the link and route to screen?

I found the solution. First use a deep link validator like, https://yurl.chayev.com/, and you should see an error, ContentType = []. The array should read application/json for the aasa file.
To fix this, edit the .htaccess file (located in the same directory /public_html) and add the following lines:
<FilesMatch "apple-app-site-association">
ForceType application/json

This will match the aasa file when it's trying to be read and force the content type to be read as json.
